# Getting error message on fresh install

Tags: database, drush, installation

I am trying to install drupal using drush site-install and keep getting the following error at the top of the page.

Warning: Illegal string offset 'field' in DatabaseCondition->__clone() (line 1817 of /var/www/mydrupalsite/includes/database/query.inc).

Even when I logout of administrator, the error still pops up at the top of the page. Can anyone explain what is going wrong and how to get rid of these messages? Everything else seems to have installed properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're installing a current version of Drupal 7, that error appears to have been fixed in an earlier version.

https://drupal.org/node/1622886